# Microsoft speech recognizer stops recognizing

Tags: wpf, speech-recognition

I am having trouble with the Microsoft speech recognizer. I am trying to make it constantly listen to me, and only after the word HELLO is recognized, it shows what I said. This part appears to be working, but after 15-20 seconds as the object "sre" is destroyed (as i think) the recognizer stops responding.

```
 static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> words = new List<string>();
            int count = e.Result.Words.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                words.Add(e.Result.Words[i].Text);
            }
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.7)
            {
                if (words[0].ToString() == "Hello")
                {
                    switch (count)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            t.Text = words[1];

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            t.Text = words[1] + " " + words[2];  
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeSpeechGrammar()
        {
            t = UserMessage;

            SpeechRecognitionEngine sre= new SpeechRecognitionEngine();


            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);


            var grammarBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
            grammarBuilder.Append(new Choices("Hello"));
            grammarBuilder.AppendWildcard();


            sre.BabbleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            sre.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

            var CommToRecognize = new Choices();

            CommToRecognize.Add(new string[] { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Grey" });

            grammarBuilder.Append(CommToRecognize);

            Grammar g = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);

            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
```

So, there is the `RecognizeMode.Multiple` mode:

```
 sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Should I be using this mode instead? Or is there something else that I am doing wrong?